# Linking google-appengine native model to Django model

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I've ported my GAE project to django-nonrel, and now I would like to have link from my object to Django User object:

```
class Opinion(google.appengine.ext.db.Model):
  ...
  author = db.ReferenceProperty(django.contrib.auth.User)
```

Unfortunately, that's not possible, since you only can link GAE models this way.

Question - what's the best way to solve this? Is it possible or should I work it around somehow?

I don't want to migrate my old GAE model since I already have a bunch of data there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial googling and searching brought me nothing good:

[On django-nonrel list](http://groups.google.com/group/django-non-relational/browse_thread/thread/d08f38dc2f89daff/4d62a92297a9c1f6?lnk=gst&q=%20appengine%20ReferenceProperty#4d62a92297a9c1f6) I read:

> You cannot use appengine model into django-nonrel. You need alter all 
>   your models to django proper. That is, use original 
>   django-registration app not the appengine-patch provided registration.

[Another question](http://groups.google.com/group/django-non-relational/browse_thread/thread/69aa296799e9f929/d72e220c8a806c0f?lnk=gst&q=%20appengine%20ReferenceProperty#), exactly like mine, was left unanswered.

... and I've found [another place](http://groups.google.com/group/django-non-relational/browse_thread/thread/4b01db7e94f5ddde/99ef1b45826e4a3d?lnk=gst&q=%20appengine%20ReferenceProperty#99ef1b45826e4a3d) where people recommend switching to Django models.

I guess that's that then, there is no way of doing what I need, one needs to migrate.

Comment: Why are you trying to use App Engine models in django-nonrel anyway? The attraction of django-nonrel for Django users is that it lets you use its models.

Comment: @Nick Johnson I have a lot of data in old AppEngine models. I don't like the idea of converting all of that, unless it's easy doable? Unfortunately, I didn't find any info on upgrading existing dataset either.